# Add multiple text field

Tags: flutter, widget

I don't know hot ot add multiple text field or box where you can write and eventually how to tranform these box to a textfield that can be toggled (show/hide)

I am expecting that when I click in this box I can write and when I press enter creates new one and with a shorcut turning one of those to tooglle text field like in Notion.

Comment: What did you try already? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I ahve just a textfield, I don't know if you used Notion but in that when you open a blank page you can write stuff and when press enter creates new box where you can write just below all of this in a bigger box. You can even turn the field where you can write into other things like toggle box or list. I'd like this behavior.